# VBS script To Start Remote Registry Service For Computer and Set Registry Key For Remote Computer

Tags: windows, service, vbscript

I have a script I'm trying to get working here. The first half of my script starts a remote service which I need to set the registry keys correctly within our environment.

I am facing a problem with the registry key creation using VBS. I spent some time researching this and thought I had found a sound way of doing this but testing on my local machine I cannot get a specific key set using VBS.

I don't receive any errors. I have tried to echo SetStringValue which returns "5".

If I could get another set of eyes on this to see what I'm doing wrong that would be great. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
                ''Check to see if remote registry is started
  strComputer = "."
  StartService ".", "RemoteRegistry", True

Sub StartService(Computer, ServiceName, Wait)
  Dim cimv2, oService, Result

  'Get the WMI administration object    
  Set cimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &
    Computer & "\root\cimv2")

  'Get the service object
  Set oService = cimv2.Get("Win32_Service.Name='" & ServiceName & "'")


  'Path = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & Computer & _
  '  "\root\cimv2:Win32_Service.Name='" & ServiceName & "'" 

  'Get the WMI administration object of the service    
  'Set oService = GetObject(Path)

  'Check base properties
  If oService.Started Then
    ' the service is Not started
    wscript.echo "The service " & ServiceName & " is started."
    exit Sub
  End If

  'Start the service
  Result = oService.StartService
  If 0 <> Result Then
    wscript.echo "Start " & ServiceName & " error:" & Result
    exit Sub 
  End If 

  Do While InStr(1,oService.State,"running",1) = 0 And Wait 
    'get the current service state
    Set oService = cimv2.Get("Win32_Service.Name='" & ServiceName & "'")

    wscript.echo now, "StartService", ServiceName, oService.Started, _
      oService.State, oService.Status
    Wscript.Sleep 200
  Loop   
End Sub

'Create registry key

const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
'strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\RightFax Fax Printer"
    strValueName = "Print Processor"
    strValue = "RFPRINT"
    objRegistry.SetStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue)
```

Comment: check this line   Set cimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    Computer & "\root\cimv2") remove the _ since the variable is just "Computer"

Comment: Thanks! This did correct one aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After more testing the 5 meant it was a permissions issue which was why the key was not being added. I found the below wrapper which will elevate permissions then execute your script. Here it is. This solution has worked for me.

```
    '=========================================================================
        ' ElevateWscript.vbs
        ' VERSION: 1.0
        ' AUTHOR: Brian Steinmeyer
        ' EMAIL: sigkill@sigkillit.com
        ' WEB: http://sigkillit.com
        ' DATE: 1/25/2012
        ' COMPATIBLE: Windows Vista, Server 2008, and Above
        ' COMMENTS: Since the introduction of UAC in Windows, despite being an
        ' administrator you may still need to run a script with elevated
        ' privileges. For example the CommandLine property of the WIN32_Process class
        ' requires a script to be elevated in order to return valid data when the process
        ' is running as another user. Unfortunately, Windows does not provide Run As
        ' Administrator on the context of a .vbs file, which is why I made this.
        ' To use the script, pass the full path to a .vbs file to the Sub and it
        ' will prompt you to run the script elevated. If the script you need to elevate
        ' in located in the same directory as this script, you can just pass the script
        ' name. Alternatively, you can always launch your vbscript from an elevated
        ' command prompt which will use wscript or cscript elevated as well.
        ' EXAMPLE: Elevate a script using the full path
        '          Call ElevateWscript("C:\scripts\test.vbs")
        ' EXAMPLE: Elevate a script in the same directory as ElevateWscript.vbs
        '          Call ElevateWscript("test.vbs")
        '=========================================================================
        Option Explicit
        Call ElevateWscript("JoeTest.vbs")

        Private Sub ElevateWscript(scriptName)
            Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            If objFSO.FileExists(scriptName) Then
                Dim objFile: Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(scriptName)
                 objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & objFile.Path & Chr(34), "", "runas", 1
            Else
                 Wscript.Echo "Script Does Not Exist!" & vbCrLf & scriptName
            End If
        End Sub
```